# How to make looping panel?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a simple system. One of the module is to view data from Mysql. Now, I need to design the way of data to display using php in the system. So, I the way of data will be display like in the pic below.
[image: picture]

I need to 3 panel is looping when the data in the DB is exist? Can someone help me?

```
<div class="row mt5">   
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="panel" id="p1">
    <div class="panel-heading ui-sortable-handle">  
    <span class="panel-title" >Paparan Kerja Yang Dirancang :</span>
    </div>


    <div class="panel-body">    
        <div class="dd mb35" id="nestable">
            <ol class="dd-list">
                <li class="dd-item"  data-id="3">
                    <div class="dd-handle"><?php 
                    echo mysql_result($sql1, 0, "jenis_kerja"); ?></div>
                    <ol class="dd-list">
                        <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">
                            <div class="dd-handle"><?php echo mysql_result($sql2, 0, "nama_aktiviti"); ?></div>
                                <ol class="dd-list">
                                    <li class="dd-item" data-id="5">
                                        <div class="dd-handle"><?php echo mysql_result($sql3, 0, "nama_sub"); ?></div>
                                    </li>      
                                </ol>
                        </li>           
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>   
    </div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the output that you getting with your existing code ?

Comment: the output that i getting is like in the pic above. can u open it? thre are 3 panel. in each panel represent a data from a table. means, i want to this 3 panel will loop when there is data in the table. do u get it?

Comment: Can  you give me the array you got , coz i can't produce the array in my machine